# Most efficient way of tracking player skill upgrades

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

So far I have investigated two different ways of persistently tracking player attribute skills in a game. These are mainly conceptual except for the threading option I came up with / found an example for.

The case:

Solo developing a web game. Geo political simulator but with a little twist in comparison to others out there which I won't reveal.

I'm using a combination of Flask and SQLAlchemy for which I have written routes for and have templates extending into a base dynamically.

Currently running it in dev mode locally with the intention of putting it behind a WSGI and a reverse proxy like Nginx on the cloud based Linux vm.

About the player attribute mechanics - a player will submit a post request which will specify a few bits of information. First we want to know which skill, intelligence, endurance etc. Next wee need to know which player, but all of this will be generated automatically, we can use Flask-LoginManager to get the current user with our nifty user_loader decorator and function. We can use the user ID it provides to query the rest of it, namely what level the player is. We can specify the math used to decide the wait time increase later in seconds.

The options;

Option 1:

As suggested by a colleague of mine. Allow the database to manage the timings of the skills. When the user submits the form, we will have created a new table to hold skill upgrade information. We take a note of what time the user submitted the form and also we multiply the current skill level by a factor of X amount of time and we put both pieces of data into the database. Then we create a new process that manages the constant checking of this table. Using timedelta, we can check if the amount of time that has elapsed since the form was submitted is equal to or greater than the time the player must wait until the upgrade is complete.

Option 2:

Import threading and create a class which expects the same information as abovr supplied on init and then simply use time.sleep for X amount of time then fire the upgrade and kill the thread when it's finished.

I hope this all makes sense. I haven't written either yet because I am undecided about which is the most efficient way around it.

I'm looking for the most scalable solution (even if it's not an option listed here) but one that is also as practical or an improvement on my concept of the skill tracking mechanic.

I'm open to adding another lib to the package but I really would rather not.

Comment: Adding a thread has the problem that if the process is interrupted it will never complete, and is horrible load-balancing wise. On the other hand enter the information into a database with some trigger time and thats fixed and done. Then, execute a task schedule to periodically scan the database for items that fit the criteria of update time and perform new actions to those entries based on that criteria. If a task is missed or process errors it will fix in the next periodic run. Investigate Celery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment a little bit:

### In terms of scaleability:

- What if the upgrade processes become very long? Hours or days?
- What if you have a lot of users
- What if people disconnect and reconnect to sessions at different times?

Hopefully it is clear you cannot ensure a robust process with option 2. Threading and waiting will put a continuous and potentially limiting load on a server and if a server fails all those threads likely to be lost.

### In terms of robustness:

On the other hand if you record all of the information to a database you have the facility to cross check the states of any items and perform upgrade/downgrade actions as deemed necessary by some form of task scheduler. This allows you to ensure that character states are always consistent with what you expect. And you only need one process to scan through the DB periodically and perform actions on all of the open rows flagged for an upgrade.

You could, if you wanted, also avoid a global task scheduler altogether. When a user performs an activity on the site a little task could run in the background (as a kind of decorator) that checks the upgrade status and if the time is right performs the DB activity, otherwise just passes. But a user would need to be actively in a session to make sure this happens, as opposed to the scheduled task above.

Comment: Interesting points here. testable on the development Flask server properly. I found that it was fairly accurate when using a custom thread run function which did specifically what I wanted it to of the timer elapsed. I could easily run up 100 individual threads using this method, print a modulus of 60 and also at the end of the time commit the changes to the database.

However, I will certainly investigate your suggestion over the weekend and see what kind of performance and results I get.

Comment: Futher to your suggestions. I believe I will go with the DB management option.

Unfortunately I need this to be "active or inactive" session, e.g. the timer must continue regardless of if the user is currently connected or logged in etc.

A well deserved accepted answer sir, thank you for your time!

Comment: I think it will be easier to store in DB an "activated time" rather than having a timer. E.g if upgrade is activated at midnight with 4hr time delay the activation time is 4am. Then all your scheduler, or periodic checker, needs to do is evaluate the current UTC time is > 4am and if it is then upgrade the user. This is completely decoupled from the the user or session, it is simply manipulating DB attributes.

Comment: Even better you could have a _pending_upgrades_ table which effectively lists a set of upgrades not yet applied. When the job finds one that qualifies as the time check is valid it applies the upgrade to the associated user and deletes that pending job

Comment: Well I will add two new tables. Pseudo schemas: tblname - skilltracker, id and userid as foreign key of the users id, time the form submitted in time.time, then we decide the time to multiply by as in level 6 upgrade is 120 seconds multiplied by 6 = 720 seconds so we set that in a column, and also add it to the previous time for comparison and conversion in antoher column, last we have active or inactive boolean column. we have two processes, one which handles time comparisons. the other cleans the "pending" table and moves them to the history table.